# how to get device name using ip

Tags: android

I wrote code to get IP address in android  which are connected to  WIFI network,Iam getting IP address but now my task is to get DNS name or device name using that IP,I tried with below code but it is not working.can you please give me a solution.

```
 InetAddress inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName(host.ipAddress);
 String Name=inetAddr.getHostName();
```

Comment: Won't work as in...? Just getting the ip back still? Crashing? ...?

Comment: again iam getting ip instead of host name.

Comment: did you try `String Name=inetAddr.getCanonicalHostName();` ?

Comment: yes i tried with getCanonicalHostName() also but it is not working.

Comment: Check the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName%28%29)  depending on security checks you might only get the original IP back